# Angular modal data not refreshing after data change

Tags: angular

I have data that is displayed in a modal.  However, when my data is updated and parent detects this, my modal data is never updated.  Am I missing something?

**PARENT**:

```
  @Input() players: Players[] = [];

  showPlayers() {
     const modalRef = this.modalService.open(PlayersModalComponent, {
      data: { players: this.players }
     },
    });
  }

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('changes', changes);
    // This shows that players has changed and gone from say 2 players to 3 players after a few actions.  But modal doesn't update.
  }
```

**Modal**

```
this.players = this.modalRef.data.players;
```

**Modal HTML**

```
Here I just list the players and initially they are perfect. But they do not update when a new player is added and ngChanges in parent ALSO shows there is a new row.

<modal class="modal" *ngIf="players">
  <div>
    <div *ngFor="let player of players">
         {{player.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
</modal>
```

However, if new result is added --- since I am pulsing on API from parent.  The change is detected but the list of players in modals is not updated.

Comment: can you share also modal html please. And what kind of library are u using for modal ?

Comment: @pc_coder It's very basic but I added it.

Comment: Thanks what is the library for modal ? @KingKongFrog and  what is PlayersModalComponent ?

Comment: also please pit the modal .ts file too.

Comment: @KingKongFrog Please check my answer. I was facing the same problem. this is what solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Normally, everything should work straight away if you were always modifying the same instance of the `players` array ([stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/player-modal-same-instance)).
So the `players` @Input passed to your parent component is probably a new instance of an array each time.

Since the `players` property in your player modal component is only initialised once (   `this.players = this.modalRef.data.players;`); once the `players` for the parent variable changes, the `players` variable from the modal component is still pointing to the previous array.

To solve this, you can either pass an observable to the modal itself like explained in Andrei's answer, or you can explicitely modify the modal's `players` variable when the parent's `players` input changes.

You can do that either using `ngOnChanges` ([stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/player-modal-ngonchanges))

**parent.component.ts**

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if(this.modalRef && changes.players.currentValue)
    {
      this.modalRef.componentInstance.players = changes.players.currentValue;
    }
}
```

Or using a setter ([stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/player-modal-setter))

**parent.component.ts**

```
@Input() set players(players: Players[])
{
 if(this.modalRef)
 {
  this.modalRef.componentInstance.players = players;
 }
}
```

These examples rely on the fact that your `modalRef` contains an instance of the component used in the dialog

Answer (score 4):

You can use ngFor `trackBy` function to detect changes

```
<modal class="modal" *ngIf="players">
    <div>
        <div *ngFor="let player of players, trackBy: trackItem">
             {{player.name}}
        </div>
    </div>
</modal>
```

and add trackItem function

```
trackItem(item: any): any {
    return item.id;
}
```

item should have unique id

Answer (score 3):

it is expected that the modal doesn't recieve an update as you pass only the first array that you have when you call showPlayers.
to be able to update the value I propose to use observables and subsribtion to get those updates

**PARENT**

```
players$ = new BehaviorSubject<Players[]>();
@Input() set players(players: Players[]) {
  this.players$.next(players);
};
showPlayers() {
     const modalRef = this.modalService.open(PlayersModalComponent, {
      data: { players$: this.players$ }
     },
    });
  }
```

**MODAL**

```
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
   data.players$.subscribe((players) => {
    this.players = players;
    cdRef.markForCheck(); // this line probably won't be needed. added just to be sure change detection detects this change
   });

}
```

Comment: Yes, there are numerous occasions where a component won't re-mount, but you still need access to changing data. In those cases, and this one, a subscription is the way to go. It will fire whenever a change in the data occurs.

Answer (score 3):

simple solution: use a ViewChild.

parent:

```
import { ChildModalComponent } from ...

@ViewChild(ChildModalComponent) childModalComponent: ChildModalComponent;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  this.childModalComponent.updatePlayers(this.players);
}
```

modal:

```
updatePlayers(players:any) {
  this.players = players;
}
```

done.

Comment: Nice and precise #thumbsUp

Answer (score 0):

in parent .ts =

```
Players any=[];

OnChangePlayers(){
Players  = [1,2,3];
}
```

in parent .html =

```
<modalcomponentSelector [Players]="Players"></modalcomponentSelector >
```

in modal .ts :

```
  @Input() players: Players[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me show u how ur code is running actually

1-showPlayers()

2-model constructor

3-OnChanges

4-OnChanges

.

.

model constructor  has been called before so now whenever OnChanges will be called there will be no effect on model bcs u have send players to model constructor

how we can send new player to model ?
instead of sending player[] send [Observable](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable) of it so u can get next players

Use can use player observable Directly in ur model template u don't have to deal with subscription.

```
// parent
players$ = new BehaviorSubject<Players[]>();
@Input() set players(players: Players[]) {
  this.players$.next(players);
};
showPlayers() {
     const modalRef = this.modalService.open(PlayersModalComponent, {
      data: { players$: this.players$ }
     },
    });
  }
```

Model

```
players$ :Observable<Players[]>
constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
   this.players$ =  data.players$
   });

}
```

Model HTML

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let player of (players$ | async)">
         {{player.name}}
    </div>
  </div>
```